# Check if the current time is in between time A and B

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, time

Is there anyway I can check if the current time is in between two times?

Current time = 12:00 AM
Time A: 8:00 AM
Time B: 3:00 PM

This would return true, This would not:
Current time: 1:00 PM
A = 1:00 AM
B = 2:00 AM

Comment: You can use the [`-compare:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsdate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/compare:) method of `NSDate`.

Comment: You are talking NSDate's here, or strings that say "1:00 AM" ?

Comment: A NSDate that has the value *1:00 AM*

Comment: Keep in mind that an NSDate is an absolute moment in time, i.e it has day/month/year components as well, so you need to create two suitable NSDate objects against which to compare.

Comment: The hard part about this is that 1:00 AM is in between 10:00 PM and 3:00 AM. You will have to include days of the week to cover that. An NSTime class would be nice to have, but doesn't exist unfortunately.

Comment: As others have mentioned, working with **only** times (and not considering the date) greatly complicates this seemingly simple task.  For one thing, as Scott says, what if either your starting or ending time is after midnight?  (ie, range of 10PM - 3AM or 3AM to 2AM).  Also, what about time changes?  If you change from/to daylight savings time, for instance, this can break or give you unexpected results.  By far and away the best thing to do in these situations is to use a fully qualified NSDate that refers to a specific **date** AND time.  Then two simple compares works.

Comment: Inafziger: this is also far from ideal. I'm soon going to work on hours of operation for certain businesses and need to include whether a business is currently open or not. All the little things that I need to consider makes me hate date/time programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with something along these lines:

```
NSDate *timeA, *timeB; // Whatever and however you want to set these;
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

If([now compare:timeA] == NSOrderedDescending && [now compare:timeB] == NSOrderedAscending)
    // then now is between timeA and Time B
```